# Javascript serialize form as JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, serialization

I use the following function to serialize my form as a json object.

```
   $.fn.serializeObject = function()
    {
        var o = {};
        var a = this.serializeArray();
        $.each(a, function() {
            if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
                if (!o[this.name].push) {
                    o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                }
                o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
            } else {
                o[this.name] = this.value || '';
            }
        });
        return o;
    };
```

It returns me result as following :

```
{
"address": "aaaa",
"organization": "66",
"region": "44",
"nodeType": "HANGING",
"description": "asdasdasdasd",
"longitude": "45.8888",
"latitude": "45.8888"
}
```

But I need to a little different result. I need to send my select options as a object which contain id value. How i can do it with javascript function or else?

```
{
    "address": "",
    "description": "aaa",
    "nodeType": {
        "idNodeType": "WELL"
    },
    "region": {
        "idRegion": "56"
    },
    "organization": {
        "idOrganization": "66"
    },
    "location": {
        "latitude": "46.234234",
        "longitude": "45.23423"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this that I can come up with. I will show you some code that combines three so you can pick which one you prefer. 
In all cases, we are creating the path within the object before the value is applied in your serializeObject method. For that I added a recursive private method that will do it. With that solved, the only question is how to determine the final path for your value, that's where I find three different ways:

1. Write the input name with the desired path, as in:

   ```
   <input name="some.path" />
   ```
2. Use an attribute in the object to form the path. I used a data-* attribute in my example but you can easily change to use the id. For instance, this will result in a mapping of region->idRegion in the JSON object:

   ```
   <select name="region" data-form-path="idRegion">
   ```
3. Create a mapping objet to determine how to map input names to the object path, such as this:

   ```
   var mapping = {
       "country" : "location.country",
       "isForeignCountry" : "location.isForeignCountry"
   }
   ```

So, here is a sample form that we can use to demonstrate the various ways this works:

```
     <form>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="1"/>
        <input type="text" name="lasntame" value="2"/>
        <input type="text" name="photos.total" value="2"/>
        <input type="text" name="photo.items" value="face.jpg" id="b"/>
        <input type="text" name="photo.items" value="landscape.jpg" id="b"/>            
        <textarea name="userData.comments" data-form-path="1355998"></textarea>
        <select name="region" data-form-path="idRegion">
            <option value="5" selected="selected">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
        </select>
        <select name="country" >
            <option value="5" selected="selected">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
        </select>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="isForeignCountry" value="8" id="f">
        <input type="submit" name="check" value="Submit" id="g">
    </form>
```

As you can see, we have inputs named 'photos.total' and 'photos.items'. There are two 'items' so you can see that multiple valued fields still convert properly. These use the first method to be mapped to  the final value path.

We also have two items with a data-form-path attribute (an HTML5 valid data-* attribute, by the way). These will use the second method, and for bonus points, the textarea has a path in the name so it also uses the first method.

The modified code that will do the magic is as follows:

```
    $.fn.serializeObject = function(mapping)
    {
            var o = {};
            var a = this.serializeArray();
            var that = this;
            $.each(a, function() {
                var name = this.name;
                // We store current reference in a variable because when a nested path 
                // is created, the value is set on the last element of the path, 
                // instead of the JSON root 
                var currentRef = o;

                if(!mapping) {
                  // 1st way: using names with path, like 'inputname="location.latitude" '
                  if(name.indexOf('.') != -1) {
                    var path = name.split('.');
                    currentRef = createPath(o, path);
                    name = name.split('.').splice(-1,1);
                  }

                  // Second way: adding metadata (this could be simply the id instead)
                  // Bonus! supports also paths with dots
                  var idData = $("*[name='" + this.name + "']",that).data("form-path");
                  if(idData){
                    currentRef = createPath(currentRef, [name,idData]);
                    name = idData;
                  }
                }
                else {
                  // Final way: simply use a mapping between form inputs and json path
                  if(mapping[name]){                
                    var path = mapping[name].split('.');
                    currentRef = createPath(o, path);                
                    name = name.split('.').splice(-1,1);
                  }
                }

                if (currentRef[name] !== undefined) {
                    if (!currentRef[name].push) {
                        currentRef[name] = [currentRef[name]];
                    }
                    currentRef[name].push(this.value || '');
                } else {
                    currentRef[name] = this.value || '';
                }
            });

            // Recursively create a path in the obj item and return
            // the last created object reference
            function createPath(obj, pathArray) {
                var item = pathArray.splice(0,1);
                var returnObj;

                if(pathArray.length === 0) {
                    returnObj = obj;
                }
                else if(!obj[item]) {
                    obj[item] = {};
                    returnObj = createPath(obj[item], pathArray);
                }
                else returnObj = createPath(obj[item], pathArray);

                return returnObj;
            }

            return o;
    };
```

Now, if we make the call without a mapping, the result for this form is:

```
    {
        "name":"1",
        "lasntame":"2",
        "photo":{
            "total":"2",
            "items":[
                "face.jpg",
                "landscape.jpg"]
        }
        ,"userData":{
            "comments":{
                "1355998":""
            }
        },
        "region":{
            "idRegion":"5"
        },
        "country":"5",
        "isForeignCountry":"8"
    }
```

The inputs with name "photos.*" have been put in a path corresponding to their names. And the inputs with the data-form-path attribute are also correctly indented.

If modifying the HTML is not an option (and let me say you need to be more specific when asking!), the you can use an input mapping object. So if I call like this:

```
    var mapping = {
        "country" : "location.country",
        "isForeignCountry" : "location.isForeignCountry"
    }
    console.log( $("form").serializeObject(mapping) );
```

The object mapping is used instead of the other rules, resulting in:

```
    {
        "name":"1",
        "lasntame":"2",
        "photo.total":"2",
        "photo.items":[
            "face.jpg",
            "landscape.jpg"],
        "userData.comments":"",
        "region":"5",
        "location":{
            "country":"5",
            "isForeignCountry":"8"
        }
    }
```

I guess this should cover your needs. I wish you had asked with more detail, like showing your HTML and explaining what you can or can not change. Let me know if this helped you. Cheers!

Comment: Endless tnaks for your attention ! and your answer is really awesome and hepful ! ;)